# Limit the size of a set comprehension from an input

Tags: python, out-of-memory, limit, set-comprehension

Is there a way to limit the size of set comprehension when parsing an input. Here's a simple example:

```
import sys

values = {x.strip() for x in open(sys.argv[1], 'r')}

print(values)
```

The size of `values` is unbounded, but is there a way to limit it? It could be done with a for loop like below, but is there a simpler way to do that?

```
import sys

values = set()
for x in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
    values.add(x.strip())

    if len(values) > 100:
       break

print(values)
```

Comment: You are reading in a file and getting the set of characters from that file, correct?

Comment: In this example, yes. The point is just a random input that I want to limit the number of unique values read and not the number of values read.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the set as it is being built in a comprehension. But you can bound the input using `itertools.islice()`.

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

values = {x.strip() for x in islice(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 100)}
```

This does limit the size, but since sets do not allow duplicates, the resulting set may be less than 100, even if there are more than 100 values, unlike your for loop, which would stop at a set size of exactly 101.

---

> That will limit the number of values input, but I want to limit the number of unique values stored.

Limiting the inputs *does* bound the size of the output. But if you want the exact behavior of your example in fewer lines, here you go.

```
import sys

values = set()
any(values.add(x.strip()) and len(values) > 100 for x in open(sys.argv[1]))

print(values)
```

The `any()` builtin will pull from the generator expression until it either exhausts it or finds a true value, whichever comes first. The expression `values.add(x.strip())` will always return `None`, so the generator returns `True` only when `len(values) > 100`.

While this does compress your entire for loop down into one line, it is arguably no simpler. The question then is, which do you find more readable?

---

> Thanks for the additional example. It accomplishes the original goal of limiting the size of the set, but as you pointed out, it's really just another way to write the loop that I originally posted. I was hoping that there might be a way to do it inside of a set comprehension to get the benefits that come from that.

What benefits are those? You certainly *could* do this all in a comprehension, but there's really no point.

```
{x for values in [set()]
 if any(values.add(x.strip())
        and len(values) > 100
        for x in open(sys.argv[1]))
    or True
 for x in values()}
```

Like I said, you can't access the set as it is being built in a comprehension, but that doesn't stop you from using a different set. But this does the pointless extra step of copying the set.

Comment: That will limit the number of values input, but I want to limit the number of unique values stored.

Comment: Thanks for the additional example. It accomplishes the original goal of limiting the size of the set, but as you pointed out, it's really just another way to write the loop that I originally posted. I was hoping that there might be a way to do it inside of a set comprehension to get the benefits that come from that.